# How to install cpp in RHEL 6.3?

Tags: rhel, software-installation, rpm, gcc

I want to install gcc in RHEL 6.3, but it has cpp dependencies.
So I go to cpp rpm download page, but it has no rpm for 6.3 version:
[image]

Is there any other way to install cpp in RHEL 6.3?

Comment: `yum install cpp`.

Comment: @jordanm, "no package cpp available, Error: nothing to do"

Comment: Ehh, have you got a valid subscription to the RHN?

Comment: @DeerHunter , do you mean I have to purchase its service?

Comment: 8-| You can either pay for RHEL and all the support, or use CentOS/SciLinux... That's as simple as it gets.

Comment: By the way, the 'cpp' package you're seeing for "Red Hat Linux 6.2" refers to a something completely different than Red Hat *Enterprise* Linux.  Red Hat Linux 6.2 was released in the year 2000.

Comment: Seems you would have started with `yum install gcc` and let yum resolve the dependencies, which would automatically install cpp and the other required packages if you have access to the repos.